# Unterschied zwischen "schon" und "bereits"

Tags: difference

Gibt es Unterschied zwischen "bereits" und "schon"?

Zum Beispiel:

> Ich habe das schon gemacht.
>
> Ich habe das bereits gemacht.

oder ist "Ich habe das schon bereits gemacht" auch richtig?

Comment: Was sagen denn die Wörterbücher?

Comment: Both is already so I would translate both sentences to "I have already done it"

Comment: "bereits" is higher register language

Answer (score 5):

Nein, es gibt keinen wesentlichen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern, außer dass in der gesprochenen Sprache 'schon' häufiger benutzt wird. 'Bereits' findet man meiner Einschätzung nach eher in geschriebenen Texten.

Beides zusammen (hintereinander) verwendet man nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Meines Erachtens ist die Konnotation verschieden. “Ich habe das schon gemacht“ unterstreicht, wie schnell (etwa: schneller als erwartet) etwas erledigt wurde, während “bereits gemacht“ eher als Antwort auf die wahrheitswidrige Unterstellung/Annahme passt, etwas sei noch gar nicht erledigt worden. “Schon“ deutet hier also mehr auf den temporalen Aspekt, “bereits“ auf den konsekutiven Aspekt des “Gemacht-habens“ hin. Das mag aber auch lediglich mein Sprachgefühl sein, belegen kann ich es nicht.

Darüber hinaus könnte bei entsprechender Betonung auf das Wort "schon" der Satz "das habe ich schon gemacht(, aber ...)" auch Vorbehalte des Sprechenden deutlich machen. Eine gleichbedeutende Umformulierung wäre dafür wäre "das habe ich zwar gemacht,aber" - "bereits" hingegen lässt sich nicht in diesem Sinne verwenden.

Will man es unbedingt so deuten, könnte mit viel gutem Willen der Satz "Ich habe das schon bereits gemacht" in diesem Sinne also umgangsprachlich gemeint sein als: "Zwar habe ich das bereits gemacht, aber ...". Das wäre dann aber bestenfalls eine unglückliche, missverständliche Formulierung, die wohl eher vermieden werden sollte.

Answer (score 2):

Die anderen Antworten konzentrieren sich auf die Bedeutungen

- *Ich bin schon damit fertig* (z. B. obwohl es erst morgen fertig sein sollte). Hier kann man beides verwenden.
- oder auf die Bekräftigung (auch wenn du es nicht glaubst).  Da funktioniert *bereits* nicht

Es gibt mindestens eine weitere Bedeutung: ich habe Erfahrung damit,

> Ich habe das schon (*früher einmal*, *öfter* oder *oft*: diese Begriffe könnten auch explizit genannt werden) gemacht

In dieser Bedeutung würde ich *bereits* eher nicht verwenden, falsch ist es aber nicht.